# Angular promise chain from array

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have an array of urls `urls = ["/url/file_1", "/url/file_2", "/url/file_3" ... "/url/file_n"]`
and a string variable `str = ""`.
What is a best way to create a promise chain to fill `str` with content of all files from the `urls`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use $q.all

```
$q.all(urls.map(function(url){return $http.get(url)})) //create multiple requests and return the array of promises
    .then(function(results){ //an array of results
        results.forEach(function(res){ //response object https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
            str += res.data; //concat strings assuming that all get calls will return string
        });
    });
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! Maybe add some text do explain what you are doing and how it works

Answer (score 1):

That is possible using `$q.all`. Example implementation:

```
var urls = [ /* some urls */ ];
var promises = Array(urls.length);
var results = Array(urls.length);

for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    promises[i] = yourPromiseReturningFunction(urls[i]).then(function(result) {
        results[i] = result;
    });
}

$q.all(promises).then(function() {
    //Just an example, do whatever youw ant with your results here
    console.log(resulst.join('')); 
});
```

This can be done in more elegant(more functional-style) ways, this is just an example to show how it is possible. Find the documentation on `$q.all` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var stringResult = '';
promises = [];
angular.forEach(urls, function (url) {
   promises.push($htpp({method: 'GET', url: url}))
}
$q.all(promises).then(
   function () {stringResult = stringResult.concat(res)})
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this will append the results in random order and does not allow to react to all promises being resolved